# Python: how to read a doc file from azure blob storage?

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I have a docx file in a blob storage.

What I try to do is to get the link/path or url of the file in the blob to apply this function:

```
def get_docx_text(path):
    """
    Take the path of a docx file as argument, return the text in unicode.
    """
    document = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
    xml_content = document.read('word/document.xml')
    document.close()
    tree = XML(xml_content)

    paragraphs = []
    for paragraph in tree.getiterator(PARA):
        texts = [node.text
                 for node in paragraph.getiterator(TEXT)
                 if node.text]
        if texts:
            paragraphs.append(''.join(texts))

    text = '\n\n'.join(paragraphs)
    return (paragraphs,text)
```

In the parameter path of def get_docx_text(path) I would like to put the path of the file.

How can I do this ?

I tried something like this but doesn't work:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

connection_string='...'
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

client = service_client.get_container_client("name_container")

bc = client.get_blob_client(blob="bronze/txt_name.docx")

with open("txt_name.docx", 'wb') as file:

    data = bc.download_blob()

    file.write(data.readall())
```

Comment: What's the issue you're running into?

Comment: ResourceNotFoundError: The specified blob does not exist.

But I guess it's not the good method to get the path

Comment: The method is correct. Can you check if a blob by the name you specified (`bronze/txt_name.docx`) indeed exists in the blob container?

Comment: It was sink/bronze/txt_name.docx but how can I do to give the path of this file to the def get_docx_text(path) function ?

Comment: What's the name of your container? Is it `sink`?

Comment: The name of the container was okay, the error is that in this container I have a folder having a folder containing the docx file

Comment: Please try `bc = client.get_blob_client(blob="sink/bronze/txt_name.docx")`.

Comment: Thanks that's it ! And next I have to give bc to the function ?

Comment: No. Just `txt_name.docx` as that's the name of the local file where blob content is downloaded.

Comment: Thank you, how can I do the same if I receive sink/bronze/documents/doc_name.docx via a post request ?

Comment: You mean downloading the blob? Same deal - `sink/bronze/documents/doc_name.docx`. You have to specify full path of the blob in `client.get_blob_client`.

Comment: Yes I mean put the good value to get_docx_text(path)

Comment: Since you're downloading the blob in the same folder where your code is running, you just have to specify the name with which you're saving the file. For example, `txt_name.docx` in this code `with open("txt_name.docx", 'wb') as file:`.

Comment: Thank you, where the file is saved ? Is it just in memory ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank You [Gaurav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri) for providing your suggestion in the comment, converting it as answer to help other community member.

**Issue:** `ResourceNotFoundError: The specified blob does not exist`.

**Solution:** Please try with this code

```
bc = client.get_blob_client(blob="sink/bronze/txt_name.docx")
```

Since you're downloading the blob in the same folder where your code is running, you just have to specify the name with which you're saving the file.

For example:in this code

```
with open("txt_name.docx", 'wb') as file:
```