# How to read docx files from azure blob using Python

Tags: python, azure, ms-word, azure-blob-storage

How to read docx files from azure blob using Python?
I use the following code, but finally, blob_content has all unreadable characters. This code works fine for txt files but not for MS Word Documents (*.docx).

Please help if you have any solution.

```
blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(container_name, blob_name, snapshot=None)
blob_download = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
blob_content = blob_download.readall().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68804591/python-how-to-read-a-doc-file-from-azure-blob-storage

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially I tried the piece of code to read the docx file from azure blob storage through visual studio code.

In portal, I have a docx file in azure blob storage

[image]

```
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient

client=BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("<Connection string>")
serviceclient = client.get_container_client("test")
bc = serviceclient.get_blob_client(blob="sample.docx")
   with open("sample.docx", 'wb') as file:
data = bc.download_blob()
file.write(data.readall())
```

The above code worked and downloaded the docx file from azure blob storage. ***when I try to open the file it is source code editor not in docx code editor.***

**Console:**

[image]

After I used piece of code to read a docx file from which is downloaded from azure blob Storage.

**Code:**

```
import  docx
doc = docx.Document("<path of the downloaded file >")
all_paras = doc.paragraphs
for  para  in  all_paras:
print(para.text)
```

**Console:**
After I executed the above code, I am able to read the docx file successfully.

[image]